# How to close the community bumps

Tags: discussion

I've been on the site a small while - and i see the Community user bumping questions some of which , maybe even all of them, probably need to be closed/answered/something so that they don't get bumped again.  I understand its community or "crowd sourced" and should eventually happen  - but I'm a little unsure how it happens and if I can contribute - is it rep based, vote based or too hard?

Is there a method for someone other than the original poster to say a question is answered?   I see this feature used on the Microsoft sites - really really badly - so I would understand that this site will never do that - Is there any description of how old questions decay and get deleted

I see questions which are well "old" , but get bumped some have correct answers (IMHO so I get that maybe I'm wrong)- but none marked as answers and I have a feeling that bumping these with no method of saying its complete - is wasteful or could be tuned better

Comment: Is there a SE meta...?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com

Comment: If you see people "bumping" a question flag that behavior

Comment: @Ramhound its the auto bump

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - Right, well my advice still stands, just not for the community user ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see a good answer, upvote.

If you see no answers, try to answer or let it be.

If its terrible, Vote to close or flag .

Community's bumping is an *intended* behaviour though